# How can be any service injected into WebTestCase subclass in Symfony?

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

Maybe I am missing something... doh, I think so, but could not find an answer to that.

`WebTestCase` generates this constructor sample:

```
public function __construct(?string $name = null, array $data = [], string $dataName = '')
{
     parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);
}
```

Was trying to add my service as the first or last argument - Symfony throws an error:

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function Tests\AppBundle\Manager\ContactManagerTest::__construct(), 0 passed in /Library/WebServer/Documents/HEPT/vendor/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-5.7/src/Framework/TestSuite.php on line 568 and at least 1 expected in /Library/WebServer/Documents/HEPT/tests/AppBundle/Manager/ContactManagerTest.php:22
```

Should I somehow use container directly? Why is autowiring not working for `WebTestCase` classes if there is a bridge class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebTestCase are used in the context of PHPUnit (which has nothing to do with Symfony and its dependency injection).

They actually generate the kernel and its container, see this piece of code extracted from [Symfony source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/7a8b7060841eaa2494f6b64777759a7d38895d2e/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/WebTestCase.php#L35):

```
protected static function createClient(array $options = array(), array $server = array())
{
    $kernel = static::bootKernel($options);
    $client = $kernel->getContainer()->get('test.client');
    $client->setServerParameters($server);
    return $client;
}
```

This means that you can easily access the container like this:

```
$kernel = static::bootKernel($options);
$container = $kernel->getContainer();
```

Please note also that `static::$kernel->getContainer()` is available as soon as you created your client to make your test.

Comment: Thank you, but the answer is not quite on the question I asked. How can I use all services (a lot of them) in WebTestCase not specifing them in config files or elsewhere? What names will have autoloaded services so I could call them from container (if thats what you ment)?

Comment: Bottom line: you can't.  Just does not work that way.  Especially if you are talking about autowired services.  Work through the examples in the docs.

Comment: Of course you can. Maybe your problem is that your services are private? In this case you will need to specify it public for test purpose (make a special definition for tests). This is fix in Symfony 4.1 where all services are public in test environment only.

Comment: From what I can tell, the question is about injecting dependencies into test cases without any configuration.  That is not going to happen.  Sure you can pull stuff out of the container as your code shows but I think something else is being asked.  Could be wrong.

Comment: @Cerad, you are 100% right - thats what I need. I am using symfony 3.*, so there is no way I can move the whole system on 4.*
Can you please direct me to the right docs where I can find any kind of solution to my task?

Comment: @Nek, my services are public and autowired / autoconfigured.

Comment: That is not how PHPUnit works. AFAIK nobody needs to inject services in test cases. If you really needs it, then you're going to need to code it by yourself. You can probably do it with a plugin of PHPUnit https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.1/extending-phpunit.html